# Options for quick email reply to the effect of "I've just done it" or "I've taken care of it"

Tags: translation, phrase-request, letter

If I get an email request to do something, what would be some standard polite replies to the effect of "I've just done it" (what you asked for)?

Would

```
Lieber X,

habe ich gemacht.

Viele Grüße,
Y
```

be correct?  Would it be too informal or rude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no standard polite reply. The level of formality really depends on your company and with whom you are communicating.

In my company the answers range from

> Erledigt.
>
> Gruß, Y
>
> (**inhouse communication)**

to

> Sehr geehrter Herr ...,
>
> ihre Anfrage/ ihr Fall wurde abschließend bearbeitet.
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
> Y
>
> (**communication with extern)**

Often the subject line of the e-mail is adapted, too:

> Re: Anfrage zu Text - erledigt

---

Regarding your message "habe ich gemacht." is grammatically correct, but "habe ich bearbeitet" or "ist erledigt" sounds more professional.

Comment: One key point is still missing: *a **standard** reply does not really exist.* The short version *(ist) erledigt* comes close to that, but only on a very colloquial level.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf, richtig. ich hab noch einen Satz ergänzt.